# ExecuteExcel4Macro with Excel 4 macros disabled

Tags: excel, vba, excel-4.0

I was wondering if anyone knows, whether
`Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "someCommand"`
is still going to work when Microsoft [disables Excel 4 macros by default](https://twitter.com/GelosSnake/status/1446192775087722497). When I myself tick the option in the Trust Center now in Office 365, the command still works flawlessly (though that does sound like a potentially unwanted behaviour, doesn't it?). So, does anyone know anything about that?

For backgorund, I only need one command which is to my knowledge not replacable: `Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"",False/True)"`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how you can run a macro with macros explicitly disabled in the application? Or are you asking how you can enable macros without going into the settings and enabling macros?

Comment: You can use `CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"` instead if you want to hide the ribbon. Run it again (twice), to show the ribbon, it's a toggle.

Comment: @Toddleson Thank you for your answer! I'm asking whether it will still be possible to run the ```ExecuteExcel4Macro```-command, when macros are enabled but Excel-4.0 macros are not (which is gonna be the default in future versions). To enable Excel-4.0 macros the user would have to enter the Trust Center and disable the CheckBox which is probably too much to ask

Comment: @RyanWildry Thank you! Unfortunately ```CommandBars.ExecuteMso "HideRibbon"``` does not do the same since the ribbon is only minimized but not hidden. I tried a lot of different methods and as I said, I did not find an equivalent which does the exact same thing

Comment: Maybe `CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"`? This is also a toggle.